# What is a Profound Word™?

Tags: knowledge, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Profound Word™, otherwise it is a Workaday Word™.

Use the following examples to find the rule.

| Profound Word™ | Workaday Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| ABLATE | DEFLATE |
| LOCATE | EXTRICATE |
| DATE | FORNICATE |
| NOMINATE | PRELATE |
| INFINITE | FINITE |
| IMPERATE | PROSTRATE |
| INDICATE | GESTURE |

CSV version:

```
Profound Word™,Workaday Word™
ABLATE,DEFLATE
LOCATE,EXTRICATE
DATE,FORNICATE
NOMINATE,PRELATE
INFINITE,FINITE
IMPERATE,PROSTRATE
INDICATE,GESTURE
```

Comment: It is good that you cut in half the length of your puzzle, but If I may insist on removing the excel table, and, perhaps, the unnecessarily header, and how about instead keeping the text version only?

Comment: @Matsmath I see nothing wrong with the image, but typically with these puzzles a text version is included.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A word is called a Profound Word™ if:

> it is related to a grammatical case.
>  Ablate --> Ablative
>  Locate --> Locative
>  Date --> Dative
>  Nominate --> Nominative
>  Infinite --> Infinitive
>  Imperate --> Imperative
>  Indicate --> Indicative

They are called profound because:

> These cases are used in Latin and Latin always sounds profound